# Entering means, standard deviations and numbers in sample

Tags: statistics, stata, mean, standard-deviation, table-statistics

In Stata, I have, For example,

low physical activity for people aged 18-24: mean=45.5, SD=2.23, number in sample=2672

low physical activity for people aged 75 and above: mean=68.07, SD=3.11, number in sample=1109

and many other groups...

How can I import these numbers and analyze them (e.g. t-test) as they are?

Comment: See `help ttesti`